# Count number of function calls per second for a specific program

Tags: c++, performance, profiling, perf

The following command:

`perf record -e cpu-clock my_program`

gives the output shown below:

[image]

How can I also get information on how many times each function was called in one second?

Comment: You can extend [this solution](https://bristot.me/using-perf-probe-to-measure-execution-time-of-user-space-code-on-linux/) to instead count the number of function calls.

Comment: I tried making it work but still had some issues. I created a new question that you can have a look for some insight [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72775424/perf-probe-is-not-working-for-the-specific-event-i-want]