# Perf probe is not working for the specific event I want

Tags: c++, linux, performance, perf

I have compiled [this](https://github.com/gyoto/Gyoto/tree/da5b07150bcdfe0626eb1ed1a2edf5fd5ce13096) open source software and would like to use `perf` to get some statistics. What I have tried is setting probes for the specific function of interest, namely `KerrBL::chrostoffel` inside `lib/KerBC.C`. But if I try running

`perf probe -x /usr/local/bin/gyoto -F`

Fails to show this specific function that I want. Trying to place a probe with

`perf probe -x /usr/local/bin/gyoto [args] 'KerrBL::chrostoffel'`

throws the error:

```
The /home/user/Gyoto/bin/gyoto file has no debug information.
Rebuild with -g, or install an appropriate debuginfo package.
Error: Failed to add events.
```

But as far as I know, I did enable debug info during compilation.

How should I properly place a probe in this specific case?

Comment: How did you build the debug build? A brief look at that project indicates `./configure` has an `--enable_debugging` flag. Did you use that?

Comment: I believe the only accepted argument is `--disable_debugging`, but that will remove the custom debug code inside the app, it wont alter the compilation flags. So what I did is try to alter the makefile and add the `-g` option.